# .htaccess rewrite - filename.html to /?c=filename

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I need it to work with all html URLs (except index), I tried using `.htaccess` with no luck.

For example... change this link from: `http://www.example.com/signup.html` to `http://www.example.com/?c=signup`.

Also if I enter directly to `http://www.example.com/?c=signup`, it must mirror `http://www.example.com/signup.html`.

**EDIT**
I found the way to do that, except for the case that I enter directly to the .html file, in that case, it does not rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %1.html [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?$ %1.html [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

To *redirect* (presumably you meant "redirect", not "rewrite") from `signup.html` to `/?c=signup` then you can do something like the following before your existing rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html$ /?c=$1 [R,L]
```

The *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable prevents a redirect loop when your existing directive rewrites to the `.html` file.

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect. Change the `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent, but only once you have confirmed it's working OK.

Your existing directives could be tidied, in summary:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect from signup.html to /?c=signup
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html$ /?c=$1 [R,L]

# Rewrite from /?c=signup to signup.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^c=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ %1.html [QSD,L]
```

Presumably, you want to discard the `c=` query string from the rewritten *substitution*?

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much! I removed the "/" from "RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html$ /?c=$1 [R,L]"  to be like this:  "RewriteRule ([^.]+)\.html$ ?c=$1 [R,L]" because I am working with a subfolder.

Comment: Glad you got it working. However, if you simply remove the slash prefix on the _substitiution_ then it won't work unless you also set the `RewriteBase` directive to that subdirectory.

Comment: I am using RewriteBase /filehost/